# Assistance needed with pointers and arrays

Tags: c

Ok, so I am writing a program that reads input from a file and puts them into arrays. I am trying to use pointers with arrays so I can point to a certain spot in an array and add a user defined float to the float that already exists.

This is my code so far:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int menu1();

    int main()
    {
        FILE * ifp = fopen("input2.txt","r"); //Open the input file
        int cars = 5, i , j, k; // Initialized cars and counters i, j, and k
        char *VIEW="VIEW", *BID="BID", *CLOSE="CLOSE", choice1[20]; //Initialize character arrays
        float START_BID[5]={0.00}, MIN_BID[5]={0.00}, CUR_BID[5]={0.00}, USR_BID[5]=0.00}; 
        int compareLimit = 100, selection=0;

        //Scan the file and appropriate the numbers into their respective arrays
        for (i = 0; i < cars; i++)
            {
                fscanf(ifp, "%f %f", &START_BID[i],&MIN_BID[i]);
            }


        printf("Welcome to the Silent Auction\n\n");
        menu1(); //Display the menu
        scanf("%s", &choice1); //



        int result = strncmp(choice1, VIEW, compareLimit); //Compare two strings
        if(result == 0)
        {
            selection = selection + 1;

        }


        int result2 = strncmp(choice1, BID, compareLimit); //Compare two strings
        if(result2 == 0)
        {
            selection = selection + 2;

        }

        int result3 = strncmp(choice1, CLOSE, compareLimit); //Compare two strings
        if(result3 == 0)
        {
            selection = selection + 3;
        }


        while (selection < 3)
    {
            if (selection == 1)
            {
                printf("Number\tCurrent Bid\tMinimum Increase\n");
                printf("1\t$%.2f\t\t$%.2f\n",CUR_BID[0], MIN_BID[0]);
                printf("2\t$%.2f\t\t$%.2f\n",CUR_BID[1], MIN_BID[1]);
                printf("3\t$%.2f\t\t$%.2f\n",CUR_BID[2], MIN_BID[2]);
                printf("4\t$%.2f\t\t$%.2f\n",CUR_BID[3], MIN_BID[3]);
                printf("5\t$%.2f\t\t$%.2f\n",CUR_BID[4], MIN_BID[4]);

                menu1();
                scanf("%s", &choice1);
            }


            else if (selection == 2)
            {
                int k;
                float usr_bid;

                printf("Which auction would you like to bid on? (1-5)\n");
                scanf("%d", k);

                if (CUR_BID[k - 1] = 0.00)
                    MIN_BID[k - 1] = START_BID[k - 1];
                else
                    MIN_BID[k - 1] = CUR_BID[k - 1] + MIN_BID[k - 1];

                printf("The minimum bid is %.2f\n", MIN_BID[k - 1]);
                printf("How much would you like to bid?\n");
                scanf("%f", usr_bid);

                if (usr_bid < MIN_BID[k-1])
                    printf("Sorry, that bid is not high enough.\n");
                else
                    CUR_BID[k - 1] = usr_bid + CUR_BID[k - 1];

                menu1();
                scanf("%s", &choice1);
            }

            else
            {
               int i;
               int auction = 1;

               for (i=0; i < cars; i++)
               {
                    for (auction = 1; auction < cars; auction++)
                    {
                        while (CUR_BID[i]!= 0.00)
                            printf("Auction %d sold for $%.2f", auction, CUR_BID);

                    }
               }
            }
    }



            fclose(ifp);



        return 0;
    }


    int menu1()
    {
        printf("Please make a selection (In all caps):\n");
        printf("\tView Auctions [VIEW]\n");
        printf("\tBid on an Auction [BID]\n");
        printf("\tClose Auctions [CLOSE]\n");

    }
```

My program works up to the while loop where `else if (selection == 2)` is. It asks me which 
auction I want. And when I give it a number, it just freezes, crashes, and doesn't give me any errors other than `Process terminated with status -1073741510`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since `menu1()` doesn't return a value, it should be declared and defined with the return type of `void`.  Further, your compiler should be warning you about this — what other warnings are you ignoring?

Comment: My compiler isn't giving me any warnings right now.

Comment: So then would it just be `int menu1(void);`?

Comment: I'd make my compiler complain unless I wrote: `void menu1(void);` — requiring a formal prototype and the `void` return type. I'd make it `static` too, but that's partly my quirk. However, it is a good idea to make everything that is not referenced from another file `static` in the file where it is defined — and the bigger the project, the more valuable that discipline becomes. The declaration `int menu1();` simply says "there is a function called `menu1()` that returns an `int`; it takes an indeterminate fixed argument list". It can't be a varargs function; those must be declared before use.

Comment: "My compiler isn't giving me any warnings right now." -- Then you're misusing it ... you should set your warning levels high.

Answer (score 2):

The pointers you pass to scanf() are incorrect.

Change:

```
   scanf("%d", k);
```

to

```
   scanf("%d", &k);
```

and change:

```
scanf("%s", &choice1); //
```

to

```
 scanf("%s", choice1); //
```

in two places.

Comment: Ok, so I did those changes, and now when I try to use the `bid` option in the menu, it keeps bringing up the `if (selection == 1)` loop.

Comment: @Drieke Take the time to debug your program. If you don't know what that means, learn ... there are plenty of references on how to debug.

Comment: Ok, I found that the first time it asks me for a selection, its before the while loop. The other times it asks, its inside the while loop, so the selections don't change. Do you know if there's a way to change the value of `selection` from inside the while loop? I need to be able to go back and forth and quit whenever I want.

Comment: @Drieke Move the part where you change `selection` inside the while loop( from the line `int result = strncmp...` until the while loop). Note that there's one more scanf that needs fix: `scanf("%f", &usr_bid);`

Comment: And create a function to handle the whole of the prompting for option and parse response, in lieu of the `menu1()` function.  You'll move a whole pile of code into that.  Ideally, you'll clean up the code.  Making people SHOUT at your program is not nice, either.  Generally, in C code, you define macros and enumeration constants in upper-case; other names are in lower-case (old school) or mixed-case (newer school).